# How to use CSS 'content' property with the 'option' tag?

Tags: html, css

How to add CSS 'content' to the 'option' tag? I would like to achieve e.g: "Name: Volvo".

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  option:before {
    content: "Name: ";
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put it this way : `<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Name: Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Name: Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Name: Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Name: Audi</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Because I would like to know how to use 'content' with <option>. Above, this is only a small example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, pseudo-elements don't work for image, input, select options.

One option is to wrap select inside and div and use `:before` content

```
<body>
  <div>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div::before{
  content:"Name: "
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PRwreg

Other option is to use javascript or jQuery to add content "Name:"